# cvPerspectiveTransform: What am I supposed to provide?

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, transformation, homography

I'm trying to use `cvPerspectiveTransform` to transform four 2D points. I got the transformation matrix (3x3) already through `cvFindHomography`. I can't figure out what kind of structure to provide to not run into some error.
Would anybody be so kind to show me how to do it with these points?

- x:y
- 0:0
- 640:0
- 0:480
- 640:480

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.0 on Win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to initialize your matrices correctly. It's probably not the most elegant, but it works:

```
CvMat* input = cvCreateMat(1, 4, CV_32FC2);
CvMat* output = cvCreateMat(1, 4, CV_32FC2);

float data[8] = {0,0,0,640,480,0,640,480};

for (int i =0; i < 8; i++)
{
    input->data.fl[i] = data[i];
}

cvPerspectiveTransform(input, output, matrix_from_cvFindHomography);
```

The C++ API offers a more intuitive implementation. Many OpenCV functions, like perspectiveTransform, accept vectors of points as inputs, which can be initialized in this manner:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> inputs;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> outputs;

inputs.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));
inputs.push_back(cv::Point2f(640,0));
inputs.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,480));
inputs.push_back(cv::Point2f(640,480));

cv::perspectiveTransform(inputs, outputs, matrix_from_findHomography);
```

Comment: I'm not constrained to the C API in any way. It's just quite annoying to find a functions documentation as there seems to be no general documentation of the whole library save for alot of trial and error.

Comment: I understand your frustration. Please see my edited answer for a more intuitive approach. If it is not sufficient, please let me know what you still require.

Comment: I'll have to choose one approach in the end but its working as a prototype now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a 3x3 cv::Mat of floats, you can convert that to (if you want double change all the f's to d's)

```
cv::Matx33f transform(your_cv_Mat);
cv::Matx31f pt1(0,0,1);
cv::Matx31f pt2(640,0,1);
...
pt1 = transform*pt1;
pt2 = transform*pt2;
...
```

make sure you normalize by the third coordinate, read up on homogenous coordinates if that does not make sense

```
pt1 *= 1/pt1(2);
pt2 *= 1/pt2(2);
...
cv::Point2f final_pt1(pt1(0),pt1(1));
cv::Point2f final_pt2(pt2(0),pt2(1));
```

You do not need to do this with Matx, it will work with cv::Mat just as well.  Personally I like Matx for working with transforms because its size and type is easier to keep track of and its contents can be more easily viewed in the debugger.

Comment: This seems the usual, mathematical way. I'm more interested in the specific usage of 'cvPerspectiveTransform' as I wasn't able to finde sufficient information. Thanks though.

Comment: @vendetta is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418471/opencv-help-on-cvperspectivetransform) what you are looking for?

Comment: It kind of is and I found it before but have no idea how to set `CV_32FC2` correctly.

Comment: @vendetta are you saying that replacing CV_64FC2 in the link I gave you with CV_32FC2 does not work?

Comment: I did so and figured out how the matrix is stored and that I could access it like an array, thank you.